# Check whether the derived set of the following set is $[0,1]$ or not.

Tags: real-analysis

**Problem** $:$

> Let $A = \{1 , \frac  {1} {2} , \frac  {1} {4} , \frac {3} {4} , \frac {1} {8} , \frac {3} {8} , \frac {5} {8} , \frac {7} {8} , \frac {1} {16} , \frac {3} {16} , \frac {5} {16} , \frac {7} {16} , \frac {9} {16} , \frac {11} {16} , \frac {13} {16} , \frac {15} {16} , … \}$.Then find the derived set $A’$ of $A$.

**My attempt** $:$

Let $B = A \cup \{0\}$.Then $B’ = A’ \cup (\{0\})’ = A’$.We claim that $A’ = [0,1]$.For proving this let us take an element $c \in [0,1]$.Then either $c \in B$ or $c \in [0,1]  \setminus B$.Let us take $\delta > 0$ arbitrarily.

**Case-1 :**

Let $c \in B$. Then either $c=1$ or $c$ is of the form $\frac {2m+1} {2^{n}}$ where $n \in \mathbb N$ and $m$ is any non-negative integer such that $m < \frac {2^{n} – 1} {2}$ or in other words $m \leq [\frac  {2^{n} – 1} {2}]$.

Let $c=1$.Then there exists $k \in \mathbb N$ such that $0 < \frac {1} {2^{k}} < \delta$.Then clearly $1 \neq 1 -  \frac {1} {2^{k}} \in (1 - \delta , 1 + \delta)$.Now $1 - \frac {1} {2^{k}} = \frac {2^{k} – 1} {2^{k}} = \frac {2(2^{k – 1} – 1) + 1} {2^{k}}$.Since $2^{k – 1} – 1 < 2 ^{k}$ so we have $1 - \frac {1} {2^{k}} \in B$.This shows that $1$ is a limit point of $B$.Now let $c \in B \setminus \{1\}$.Then there exists a natural number $n$ and a non-negative integer $m$ satisfying $m < \frac {2^{n} – 1} {2}$ such that $c = \frac {2m + 1} {2^{n}}$.Now there exists $r \in \mathbb N$ such that $0 < \frac {1} {2^{r + n}} < \delta$. Then clearly $c - \frac {1} {2^{r + n}} \in (c - \delta , c + \delta)$ and  $c - \frac {1} {2^{r + n}} = \frac {2m+1} {2^{n}} - \frac {1} {2^{r + n}} = \frac {2^{r + 1} m + 2^{r} – 1} {2^{r + n}} =\frac {2(2^{r}m + 2^{r – 1} – 1) + 1} {2^{r + n}}$.Now since $m < \frac {2^{n} – 1} {2}$ so we have $2^{r}m + 2 ^{r – 1} – 1 < \frac {2^{r} (2^{n} – 1)} {2} + 2^{r – 1} -1 = 2^{r + n -1} < 2^{r + n}$.Which shows that $c - \frac {1} {2^{r + n}} \in B$.This shows that $c$ is a limit point of $B$.Thus every element of $B$ is a limit point of $B$.

**Case-2 :**

Let $c \in [0,1]  \setminus B$. Then either $c \in [0.\frac {1} {2}]$ or $c \in [\frac {1} {2} , 1]$.If $c \in [0.\frac {1} {2}]$ then we rename this interval as$ [a_{1} , b_{1}]$ otherwise we take the interval $[\frac {1} {2} , 1]$ as $ [a_{1} , b_{1}]$.Then $a_{1} , b_{1} \in B$ and $(b_{1} – a_{1}) = \frac {1} {2}$.Let $c_{1} = \frac {a_{1} + b_{1}} {2}$.Then either $c \in [a_{1} , c_{1}]$ or $c \in [c_{1} , b_{1}]$.We rename this interval $[a_{2} , b_{2}]$ in which $c$ lies.Then according to the construction of $B$ it is clear that $a_{2} , b_{2} \in B$ and $(b_{2} – a_{2}) = \frac {1} {2^{2}}$. Continuing this process we have a strictly decreasing sequence of closed and bounded intervals $\{[a_{n} , b_{n}]\}$ each term of which contains the element $c$ such that $a_{n} , b_{n} \in B$ and $(b_{n} – a_{n}) = \frac {1} {2^{n}}$.So there exists $p \in \mathbb N$ such that $0 < \frac {1} {2^{p}} < \delta$.So the diameter of the interval $[a_{p} , b_{p}]$ containing $c$ is strictly lesser than the diameter of the interval $(c - \delta , c + \delta)$.This implies that at least one of $a_{p} , b_{p}$ is in $(c - \delta , c + \delta)$.This shows that $c$ is a limit point of $B$.So every element of $[0,1] \setminus B$ is a limit point of $B$.

Again if I take any element $c$ which is greater than $1$ (or less than $0$) then we can find out suitable $\delta > 0$ such that $c - \delta > 1$ (or $c + \delta < 0$).Then easily the set $(c - \delta , c +\delta) \cap B$ can be shown to be empty.Which shows that they are not limit points of $B$.

Hence $B’ = [0,1]$ and consequently $A’ = [0,1]$.Which proves our claim.

Comment: I guess your answer is right but there is an easier way. Since it is obvious that $A' \subset [0, 1]$ the problem is to show $[0, 1] \subset A'$. Then this can be shown once you notice that every open set of $[0, 1]$ contains a set of the form $(m/2^n, (m+1)/2^n]$.